# Expect deletes ^H after spawn bash -c

Tags: bash, sed, expect

I have an expect script that grabs a bunch of configs and outputs them to separate files. The files though have a bunch of `^H`'s though I'd like to clean out. I used the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to put it in the expect script, but when it runs it just does it. The sed works fine in bash, but fails in expect. How can I delete the `^H` from the files?

```
foreach host $ip {
        set output [ open "$host" w ]
        set timeout 2
        spawn ssh -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss $username@$host
        expect {
                eof {wait; spawn telnet $host;
                        expect "ame:";
                        send "$username\r"}
        }
        expect "word:"
        send "$password\r"
        expect "#"
        send "$command\r"
        sleep 2
        expect {
                "ore--" { send -- " "; puts $output $expect_out(buffer); exp_continue}
                "#" {send -- "exit\r"}
        }
        puts $output $expect_out(buffer)
        close $output
        close
}
foreach host $ip {
        spawn bash -c "sed -i 's/^H//gi; s/--More--//g' ./$host"
}
close
```

Here's what it looks like when it runs:

```
spawn bash -c sed -i 's//gi; s/--More--//g' ./192.168.50.1
spawn bash -c sed -i 's//gi; s/--More--//g' ./192.168.51.1
spawn bash -c sed -i 's//gi; s/--More--//g' ./192.168.52.1
```

Comment: You have not asked a question. What what do you need help with

Comment: I added the question

Comment: could you try `spawn bash -c "sed -i 's/\\o010//gi; s/--More--//g' ./$host"` (two backslashes might help) and post the output?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming an ASCII-based locale, this should work:

```
tr -d '\010' < file > file.new
```

`\010` is octal 8, which is the ASCII equivalent of backspace.

Comment: Nope, it still just deletes the character before it. It ended up running `spawn bash -c tr -d ' 192.168.50.1 192.168.50.1.txt`

Answer (score 0):

For calling out to sed, since you don't need to interact with the process, you can use `exec` instead:

```
foreach host $ip {
    exec sed -i {s/^H//gi; s/--More--//g} ./$host
}
```

Using Tcl's version of single quotes, which are `{}`